# Using flask_wtf validators to control input filed not working

Tags: python, flask

This is the code in `forms.py`

```
url = FileField(
        label="File",
        validators=[
            DataRequired("Please upload your file")
        ],
        description="File"
)
```

In HTML:

```
{{ form.url }}
```

When I try to remove the `required` attribute in `views.py` by emptying `validators` like this:
`form.url.validators = []`

It's not working, there's still a `required` in the input filed, how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the list of validators there is the `Optional()` validator which allows you to make an HTML field **optional**. Here's how to use it:

```
url = FileField(label="File", validators=[Optional()], description="File")
```